# Web API 2 and OData Security

Tags: excel, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web application that is exposing Rest api using Web Api 2.

I need to expose some oData feeds for some very specific entities. As Excel 2013 needs to be supported for using the oData feed, we have to use oData v3

I can't find how to secure the oData endpoints properly.

Using the Authorize attribute, Excel says that the feed is not valid while I can still get my data in the browser.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

various authentication methods can be found@  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/tags/authentication/ , please check it out.